# ajax not calling controller function laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am using following code in javascript function

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: '/delprofile',
    success:alert("Record deleted."),
        error:  alert("Record not deleted.")
});
```

and my route and function are as :

```
public function delprofile (Request $request){  
   DB::table('education')->where('id','=',7)->delete();
   return true;
}
```

`Route::post('/delprofile','ProfileController@delprofile');`

The query is not performing any deletion.

Comment: It should be `Route::delete` I think

Comment: I would temporarily switch the route to `GET` and call the URL directly. Or debug via curl.

Comment: @BjörnTantau yes it execute delete query then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added **CSRF token** in ajax code

```
data: {'_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
```

Discussed [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/ajax-error-error-internal-server-error)

Answer (score 4):

As your AJAX is setting the request-method to `DELETE` you'll have to do the same with your route.

```
Route::delete('/delprofile','ProfileController@delprofile');
```

Comment: still not deleting

Comment: Is the correct controller method called? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no error, I have given all code, the main issue controller method is not being called

Comment: @YusufEkaSayogana code is being executed now but ajax error is Whoops, looks like something went wrong. while delprofile function contains only line: `DB::table('education')->where('id','=',7)->delete();`

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam turn on the debug mode dude, so you can see the error, not only "Whoops"

Comment: @YusufEkaSayogana AJAX error: error : Method Not Allowed

Comment: @YusufEkaSayogana AJAX error: error : Internal Server Error

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam are you sure use Route::delete('/delprofile','ProfileController@delprofile'); ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue comes from your JS code, you're missind the anonymos function in the both `success & error` :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: '/delprofile',
    success: function(){ alert("Record deleted.") },
    error:  function(){ alert("Record not deleted.") },
});
```

Or you could also use `done/fail` instead :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: '/delprofile',
}).done(function() {
    alert("Record deleted.");
}).fail(function() {
    alert("Record not deleted.");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried both but they are not deleting any record. Even alert(10) after this code is not being executed.

Comment: Ok please check the _network/console_ tabs in your browser developer tools, to make sure there's no error and to make sur if the request was sent or not, if the alert after you ajax query not executed that mean there's a JS error in you code...